# Feeding avconv one image after another

Tags: avconv, imagemagick

I have recently taken a bunch of images to create a time-lapse video and using `avconv` and this was surprisingly easy (after looking up the right command).

But now I want to send each image through Imagemagick's `convert` function before passing it on to avconv.

This can be done by saving the edited pictures and using these as input for `avconv`. *However,* I'd like to avoid this mainly because it takes up a lot of space.

What *I would like* to do would be something like this

- avconv runs in background
- do { some processing; make image edits; send result to `avconv`; } repeat for all images
- quit avconv saving the resulting video

How can I make on the fly picture edits when creating a time lapse video?

Comment: I'd want to point out that your question has absolutely nothing to do with Ubuntu. In the future you may want to post such things in Video.SE instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done *exactly* the way you want it done, *and you can come close*, but it'll take a lot of fiddling.

I also understand the rationale behind it: You want to treat the output of the `convert` function as temporary files that can be deleted afterwards, so instead of:

```
@!/bin/bash
convert -stretch 1280x720 -background none ~/Pictures/MyTimelapseImages/*.jpg ~/tmp/MyTempImages/*.jpg
avconv -i ~/tmp/MyTempImages/*.jpg ~/Videos/MyTimeLapsVideo.mkv
```

you want to start the image conversion process on one CPU core and at the same time start the video conversion process on another CPU core ***and delete the files already processed by avconv*** (to conserve disk space)

And it's the ***latter*** that will take the fiddling, because you'll have to `cpulimit` both `avconv` *and* `convert` that they're in *nearly perfect* sync with each other and then create *yet another process* that'll clean up the processed files.

So, yes, can be done and if you're working for a huge company that wants you to save 1,000s of bucks on their 100+ server farm, it'll be worth it.  On your system?  For yourself?  For one movie?

### Have the one you're making this movie for contribute to buying you a newer bigger hard drive!

;-)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Well saving the edited images will have to do. 
Just a thought: `avconv -f script2image -i ~/processimg.sh -r 24 out.mkv` would be a nice thing. Call the script until no image is returned.